# Should I have separate properties in Google Analytics for www.mysaas.com and app.mysaas.com?

Tags: google-analytics

I want to add both my website www.mysaas.com and the web application app.mysaas.com to Google Analytics. Should I have different properties for the two?

What are the main benefits and why not just filter the views based on the subdomain?

Comment: In addition to what Stephen said below, if you do decide to track them with the same tag, and especially if a user can go from one domain to the other because the two are interlinked in some way, don't forget to implement cross domain tracking, so that one session doesn't end up being counted as two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting both other the same property allows you to view the stats together.   That is usually desirable when the two:

- are about the same subject
- link to each other
- are run by the same people or company
- have the same people that want to see the stats

If you put them on separate properties you will never be able to view the stats together.   Conversely, as you state in the question, you can add multiple views with filters to see the two separately even if they share a property.   You can also create "advanced segments" to see one or the other from the main unfiltered view.